# I'm trying to connect to the backend in my app but I get an error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, node.js

This is the error message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmyE5.png)

I know it says port 2000 there, but the error is the same if I have 3000 in there. I just changed the port to get the app to re render and show the error message (if i refresh the page, it does not re render)

```
export default function Meals () {

    const [loadedMeals, setLoadedMeals] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchMeals() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/meals');
    
            const meals = await response.json();
    
            setLoadedMeals(meals)
        }
        fetchMeals()
    }, [])
```

The backend looks like this (i did not code this, its the starting project of the Udemy course i am doing)

```
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.get('/meals', async (req, res) => {
  const meals = await fs.readFile('./data/available-meals.json', 'utf8');
  res.json(JSON.parse(meals));
});

app.post('/orders', async (req, res) => {
  const orderData = req.body.order;

  if (orderData === null || orderData.items === null ) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: 'Missing data.' });
  }

  if (
    orderData.customer.email === null ||
    !orderData.customer.email.includes('@') ||
    orderData.customer.name === null ||
    orderData.customer.name.trim() === '' ||
    orderData.customer.street === null ||
    orderData.customer.street.trim() === '' ||
    orderData.customer['postal-code'] === null ||
    orderData.customer['postal-code'].trim() === '' ||
    orderData.customer.city === null ||
    orderData.customer.city.trim() === ''
  ) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message:
        'Missing data: Email, name, street, postal code or city is missing.',
    });
  }

  const newOrder = {
    ...orderData,
    id: (Math.random() * 1000).toString(),
  };
  const orders = await fs.readFile('./data/orders.json', 'utf8');
  const allOrders = JSON.parse(orders);
  allOrders.push(newOrder);
  await fs.writeFile('./data/orders.json', JSON.stringify(allOrders));
  res.status(201).json({ message: 'Order created!' });
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }

  res.status(404).json({ message: 'Not found' });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I have tried changing ports around, i've got the exact same code as the Udemy instructor so i dont know whats wrong.

I've done cd backend >> node app.js

Comment: are you sure the node server is running ? 
You can pass a callback function to app.listen to show a message in console indicating that server is running. 
Like: 
app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log("Server is running on port 3000"))
IF you did this and got this message in console then at least you are sure the server is running. 

You can then check the network tab in the browser to view the api calls activity.

You can also test your api using Postman or by entering localhost:3000/meals in the browser and make sure server is responding